# Identify empty space OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, detection, lighting

I have a webcam filming a grid with holes in it and sometimes there's a colored object on a hole and sometimes there isn't.

[image]

I'm still brainstorming, trying to find a good solution on figuring out if there's something on one of the holes or not.

How I'm doing it now is by converting the image to HSV and then setting the color range of the empty holes to being ignored, ie un-covered, squares (every hole is a ROI). The problem is that the value changes with changing room lighting.

Here's what it looks like in HSV (objects are at different positions from the first picture).

[image]

Would the solution be to figure out the room lighting first? How could one go about that? Or is there something I'm missing? How can I perfectly, no matter the lighting conditions, figure out if one of the holes is covered or not?
I'm not looking for code, but for ideas on how something like this could (hopefully easily) be achieved.

Comment: Is the room lighting monochromatic? Is it consistent across the image, or is it possible that only part of the ceiling could contain a shadow and the rest be bright? Can you add a "control" hole that will never be covered?

Comment: I like the control-hole idea, could be a good solution, even though it's possible that the ceiling could contain shadows are lamps. Still, it's a good idea worth following up on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the hole is not colored, then it has gray-scale color. So every base-color components(R,G,B) are around the same level. And then it doesn't matter if there is high brightness (RGB will be like 200,195,205) or no (RGB will be like 40,30,35). So you can count maximum difference between them and if this difference will be more than your threshold, you can say that there is a color.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. The color of the uncovered whole isn't gray, but the color of the ceiling, influenced by the lighting in the room.. or am i not following?

Comment: @Jonas What is the ceiling? There's nothing that looks like a ceiling in the images you posted. And what do you mean by "whole"? Do you mean "hole"?

Comment: Yeah, I saw and fixed the hole - whole typos, sorry about that! In the first image, all the white looking squares the nuncovered holes. The cam is filming up at the grid where the colored objects are put, so no object = ceiling. Sorry, wasn't very specific, should have clarified my setup! thanks